# Incoherent answers approach

Tags: discussion

I was doing reviews on the low quality queue when I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42919269/android-custom-launcher-development-any-way-to-determine-that-its-unloaded) where a totally incoherent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43071331/6214222) can be found:

[image]

The answer comes from a user who has been around for a year and provided a couple of legitimate answers to different questions, so I guess it's from a "real" account/user, yet the answer in question seems as an auto generated text in disguise.

It is because of this that it picked my interest, it looks like an answer a bot would provide and hopefully only a bot would upvote.

My question is, how do you approach such an answer in the queue?

It is obviously not trying to answer the question but it is also not a comment to another answer.

Should I vote to close it down with no comments? Should I leave a comment of my own and move on?
Last but not least, I think a mod or high rep user should check who upvoted it as it seems as fishy behaviour.

Comment: Only devs can see votes users make (and I think they have to do that through the DB).  Mods can check for voting rings but I do not think that can see individual votes.  Mere mortals cannot see anything about votes except how many on what days.

Comment: Bounty fishing probably.. It will get the bounty auto-awarded in a few hours... Looks malicious to me.

Comment: @Floern Isn't a bounty awarded manually by the bounty creator by accepting the answer? Or the TC?

Comment: @NahuelIanni If the OP doesn't award it, this answer (being the only one with upvotes) will get half the bounty

Comment: I was not aware of that, guess it makes more sense then.

Comment: The answer has now been deleted after receiving enough down/delete-votes

Comment: I have to admit that I have seen worse. I've tried to salvage it with an edit, please check whether it is more coherent now.

Comment: @Bergi Um, the problem with the answer is not the poor English.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If it's incoherent, downvote it.

The *"What are you talking about at all?"* comment has 7 upvotes at this moment, yet there wasn't a *single* downvote on the answer...

> *If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted).* ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty))

Downvoting a incoherent answer will also prevent it from automatically getting the bounty reward.

Comment: Many users avoid down voting because of the loss of points

Comment: Those users need to seriously re-examine their priorities.

Comment: @NahuelIanni: That's bad. Users should be less reluctant to downvote answers, at it's one of SO's __most important__ quality control mechanisms.

Comment: Not saying it shouldn't happen or that it is right, just that it is a "thing". I know many people who use SO as their CV or letter of presentation where their only objective is to showcase a nice number next to their picture, and nothing else.

Comment: My all time vote count is 5331. 4341 of those are downvotes. __2967__ of those are on answers. I still have a pretty nice number next to my profile name, despite losing almost 3k rep due to the downvotes I've cast.

Comment: Again, not trying to argue with your logic, but it is easier to get to your desired objective by adding only instead of adding and subtracting. It all depends on your objective: Do you want to show a badge to someone or help the community?

Comment: Note that you get the -1 rep refunded if the answer gets deleted afterwards.

Comment: @Floern: I'm not sure deleted posts count for vote count. Nahuel: I get what you're saying, just explaining that it's still easy to build rep while downvoting significantly.

Comment: @Cerbrus A 1%-er explaining how you hardly notice spending 3k points and why doesn't everyone do it?

Comment: @bmm6o: If you're going to put effort into getting a nice number next to your username, you're going to strife to _be_ a 1%-er. By the time you get that "nice number", the rep cost of downvotes is negligible.

Comment: @NahuelIanni Well if you see users avoiding downvotes because of the -1, you can always remind them that they can quickly gain it back multiple times over by posting good content or suggesting helpful edits.

Comment: Personally, I avoid downvoting 1-rep users because I lose rep and nothing bad happens to them.

Comment: @SomethingDark: I still downvote them because there are always sympathy votes that are going to come their way and *then* the downvotes will count (or I think they do? hopefully?).

Comment: @SomethingDark downvoting is not about punishing users for being useless, it's about signalling to readers that the post is crap. Not that anybody copies content mindlessly from Stack Overflow, right...?

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't think you've downvoted 3k answer by the way, I think you have voted either way on 3k answers. Note that on your profile the *all time* up+down is equal to *by type* question+answer. Everything else you've said here is absolutely correct though, people should just use their votes. Forget the -1 rep, it's **nothing**. A single upvote on an answer wipes that out 10 fold.

Comment: This is depressingly common. See also [this case study](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216737/200582) where a comment of mine criticising an answer as completely and utterly useless ultimately reached hundreds of upvotes while the answer being criticised only accrued a few dozen downvotes. People are really, really averse to downvoting, and it's a shame.

Comment: Oh, @DavidG: you're right. Still, I'm sure it's more than 2500

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that overall you've lost far less than that after you factor in deleted posts, possibly 50%, I might even stretch as low as 20%. I wonder if it's worth asking for some stats as this can't be extracted from SEDE.

Comment: Iv'e only got 990 upvotes altogether. I've voted on 2967 answers. That means at least ~2000 answer votes must be downvotes, right?

Comment: @bmm60 "A 1%-er explaining how you hardly notice spending 3k points and why doesn't everyone do it?" -- Logic fail. Downvoting doesn't cost you 3K points. Familiarize yourself with the concept of *proportionality*.

Answer (score 4):

1. If it's not useful (and this one sounds like it's out to lunch) you should downvote it. No need to ask on this. The upvotes are weird but it doesn't preclude you from downvoting.
2. The OP should mod flag the question and explain the situation. A mod can refund the bounty before it gets awarded

Beyond downvoting, I'm not sure there's anything for you to do here. Without understanding the subject matter, I'm not sure the answer is flaggable.

EDIT: I wrote this not thinking of voting rings. Sham voting should be flagged. Bad answers should not.

Comment: If eight users agree the answer is just plain weird, and it still has significant upvotes, it's very likely to be flag-worthy in addition to downvote-worthy.

Comment: @Pekka웃 It's far more likely that 3 20k+ users agree and nuke it (which has happened). I tend to run off the rule that if it requires the mod to understand the subject matter, the flag will probably get rejected

Comment: yes. Just saying, if there's reason to suspect foul play, it's really ok to flag.

Comment: `I tend to run off the rule that if it requires the mod to understand the subject matter, the flag will probably get rejected` I see what you mean - but in this case I'd have flagged suspecting that the upvotes are "illegal". Which a mod can look into without understanding the answer.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Ah, good point

Comment: More likely only if it comes to their attention (by writing here for example) but as far as the low quality queue, the only flag you can use is the one without comments but it doesn't seem to be the right choice here

Comment: @NahuelIanni If you suspect voting fraud, then flagging the post for moderator attention to state that you suspect voting fraud would be merited.

Comment: Yeah, what @Pekka웃 said, if there's illegal voting anywhere, flag em. We'll take care.